Is there a counterexample for this locally un-invertible function?
I have a function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $\langle u,v\rangle \mapsto \langle A(u,v), B(u,v)\rangle$.
I am trying to understand what happens if the Jacobian determinant of $F$ vanishes at a point $\langle u_0, v_0\rangle$. Let us assume that all the partial derivatives of $F$ exist and are smooth, and that neither the derivative $\langle A_u(u_0, v_0), B_u(u_0, v_0)\rangle$ nor $\langle A_v(u_0, v_0), B_v(u_0, v_0)\rangle$ are the zero vector.
Because the inverse function theorem fails here, I believe it must be true that every neighborhood of $\langle u_0, v_0\rangle$ contains at least one other point $\langle u_1, v_1\rangle$ such that $\langle A(u_0,v_0), B(u_0,v_0)\rangle = \langle A(u_0,v_0), B(u_1,v_1)\rangle$.
But I hope to use the smoothness property of the partial derivatives to say more about the topology of this level area. Can we say for certain that there is a connected open set containing $\langle u_0, v_0\rangle$ on which $\langle A, B\rangle$ is constant? Perhaps we can say that it has dimension at least 1?
I have attempted to use the contraction mapping theorem to prove the properties of such a general region, but I'm not sure where to go next. It seems like the smoothness property implies something nice about the inverse image $F^{-1}(A(u_0,v_0), B(u_0,v_0))$, but I'm unsure how to bring this out.
edit: I found this question, which is not quite the same, but on the same topic: The level curves and the Jacobian
